# NSTimer time increment

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'm a beginner in obj-C for iOS platform and am trying to build a few simple project to build my foundation.

I have a button which increase the NSTimer time for the label, but when I use NSLog to log the time, it uses the value before time increment was implemented. I need to be able to log a updated time (after increment), as I require that value and am implementing more function into the IBAction after I solve this portion.

E.g at 15min I press, the NSLog will read it as "00:15:00.0" rather than "00:35:00.0".

```
- (IBAction)onSkipPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1200];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.timeLabel.text);
}
```

Any one know the reason for this issue? And how should I solve it such that NSLog will read it as "00:35:00.0" if I invoke this IBAction at 15min.

EDIT - The start button will start the timer and timeLabel will get the string. Sorry for missing out such a important detail. I don't think there are any other code in the project which is related to this functionality already. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.S"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    timeLabel.text = timeString;   
}
```

my IBAction to fire the timer

```
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [NSDate date];

    gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];

    //hide start button and show timeLabel
    startButton.hidden=true;
    timeLabel.hidden=false;

}
```

Comment: What behaviour do you want? It isn't clear... When you press the button you want to show the current time and what else?
When did your nstimer is created? And when is it fired / invalidated?

Comment: Is there any other code in your project related to this functionality? The code in this method only changes the value of startDate, it doesn't assign the new value to the timeLabel...

Comment: What will happen if you replace your NSLog with: NSLog(@"%@",self.startDate); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to do a few revision with tutorials involving NSTimer. And turns out all I was missing was 1 line [self updateTimer]

```
- (IBAction)onSkipPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1200];
    [self updateTimer];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.timeLabel.text);
}
```

This solve my issue and the timeLabel.text is updated for me to log the information.

Answer (score 0):

Um, why are you passing in negative 1200?

```
// this subtracts 1200 seconds from your date, no?
startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1200];
```

Shouldn't you do:

```
// add 30 minutes (60 seconds a minute x 30 minutes) to your time interval
startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 30)];
...
NSLog(@"%@",self.timeLabel.text);
```

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure about the (60*30) or -1200. Cause it was actually taught to me by another person on SO, and since it work, i didn't really try it out. But I will go test it out now since I'm on my workstation and let you know. :)

Comment: apparently using a positive number will reduce the timer instead.